# wpf Why is this path being scaled weirdly?

Tags: wpf, xaml, path, scaling

Can someone tell me why the purple path is not to the same scale as the second path? They are set in the control template for togglebutton, shown below. In addition, you can see the result here:

http://picpaste.com/weird_path-nxRoeKjb.jpg

```
           <Grid x:Name="ToggleButtonGrid"
              Background="Navy"
            >
              <Path x:Name="ExpandPath"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Stretch="Fill"
              Fill="Gray"
              Stroke="Purple"
              Data="M 0 0 L 12 0 L 12 12 L 0 12 Z" />
              <Path
              HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Fill="Gray"
              Stretch="Fill"
              Stroke="Yellow"
              Data="M 0 6 L 12 6 Z" />
            </Grid>
```

which is then set in the controltemplate for the treeview. I don't see why it is being resized. Both of them are just contained in a grid. I would expect the grid to resize, but I am getting this

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="TreeViewExpanderColumn" MinWidth="19"
              Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander"
          Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}"
          IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded,
                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
          ClickMode="Press"/>
      <Border Name="Bd"
      Grid.Column="1"
      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
      BorderThickness="0"
      Padding="0">
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header"
              ContentSource="Header"
              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"/>
      </Border>
      <ItemsPresenter 
        x:Name="ItemsHost" 
        Margin="-19,0,0,0"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
```

Comment: Grid at the top seem to be drawn correctly (when I set its width and height). Make sure the template at the bottom actually uses it, as currently it refers to `ExpandCollapseToggleStyle` which is not present here (and the sample code is incomplete).

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with using a Path to draw a line and some scaling. Not sure what was going on, but using a Line instead fixed it.

```
            <Path 
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Stretch="Fill"
              Fill="Gray"
              Stroke="White"
              Data="M 0 0 L 12 0 L 12 12 L 0 12 Z" />
              <Line 
              HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Fill="Gray"
               X1="0"
               Y1="0"
               X2="12"
               Y2="0"
              Stroke="White"
              />
              <Line x:Name="VerticalCrossBar"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Fill="Gray"
               X1="0"
               Y1="0"
               X2="0"
               Y2="12"
              Stroke="White"
              />
```